# Jetty ssl factory using http2 doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, jetty, jetty-9

I have a simple spring boot project using jetty.

I run on port 443 and use http1.1 just fine

```
@Bean(name = "containerCustomizer")
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer containerCustomizer()
{
    return (container -> ((JettyServletWebServerFactory) container).addServerCustomizers(server -> {
        // HTTPS
        SslContextFactory.Server sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory.Server();
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStoreResource(Resource.newResource(
                getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("keystore.jks")));
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("password");
        sslContextFactory.setProtocol("TLS");
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStoreType("JKS");

        HttpConfiguration https = new HttpConfiguration();
        https.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());
        SslConnectionFactory sslFactory = new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory,
                                                                   HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1.asString());
        ServerConnector sslConnector = new ServerConnector(server, sslFactory, new HttpConnectionFactory(https));
        sslConnector.setPort(443);
        server.setConnectors(new Connector[] {sslConnector});
    }));
}
```

However once I change to HTTP2 by replacing `HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1.asString()` with `HttpVersion.HTTP_2.asString()` then I get exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No protocol factory for SSL next protocol: 'HTTP/2.0' in ServerConnector@61e45f87{SSL, (ssl, http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:443}
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:317) ~[jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:81) ~[jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:234) ~[jetty-server-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73) ~[jetty-util-9.4.35.v20201120.jar:9.4.35.v20201120]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyWebServer.start(JettyWebServer.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:2.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just changing the version string isn't sufficient.

You'll also need ...

- `ALPNServerConnectionFactory` - for processing the TLS layer (known as ALPN) that selects the HTTP/2 protocol
- `HTTP2ServerConnectionFactory` - for using HTTP/2 protocol

As seen in the [embedded / Http2Server.java example](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.35.v20201120/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/Http2Server.java)

The key is that you will chain the connection types together, ALPN to HTTP2 to HTTPS.

```java
// SSL Context Factory for HTTPS and HTTP/2
SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory.Server();
// configure sslContextFactory

// HTTPS Configuration
HttpConfiguration httpsConfig = new HttpConfiguration(httpConfig);
httpsConfig.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());

// HTTP/2 Connection Factory
HTTP2ServerConnectionFactory h2 = new HTTP2ServerConnectionFactory(httpsConfig);

ALPNServerConnectionFactory alpn = new ALPNServerConnectionFactory();
alpn.setDefaultProtocol(http.getDefaultProtocol());

// SSL Connection Factory
SslConnectionFactory ssl = new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, alpn.getProtocol());

// HTTP/2 Connector
ServerConnector http2Connector =
    new ServerConnector(server, ssl, alpn, h2, new HttpConnectionFactory(httpsConfig));
http2Connector.setPort(securePort);
server.addConnector(http2Connector);
```

Comment: The link works, but holy hell is it a headache to upgrade spring boot project with jetty to http2. Had to upgrade java to java 11, then had to jump through hoops. I am starting to question whether I should continue sticking to jetty like a fanboy that I am.

Comment: Java 8u252+ supports ALPN built-in too.  But upgrading to Java 11 is recommended.